# C++ searching for one string in a set of pairs of strings

Tags: c++, set, std-pair

I have defined edges in my graph as a pair of cities, like:
`make_pair(city1, city2)`

I have stored the pairs in a `set<pair<string,string>>`

I now want to change all instances of `cityA` to `cityB`.  `cityA` could be in either the `pair.first` or `pair.second` position.

I have tried to search with following loops, but I get an error on the = sign, the assignment operator.

This code shows two ways.

What am I doing wrong?

```
for (edgeSetIter = edgeSet.begin(); edgeSetIter != edgeSet.end(); edgeSetIter++)            
    {
    if ((*edgeSetIter).first == cityA) { edgeSetIter->first = cityB; }
    else if ((*edgeSetIter).second == cityA) { (*edgeSetIter).second = cityB; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify elements of a set as they are the Key to the associative container. Exact [quote from cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/):

> In a set, the value of an element also identifies it (the value is itself the key, of type T), and each value must be unique. The value of the elements in a set cannot be modified once in the container (the elements are always const), but they can be inserted or removed from the container.

An alternative to a `set` may be using a non-associative container and: [`unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/).

Comment: Yes, one can't modify the thing one is iterating over.  Thank you !